# JDBC - Null Check Close function

Tags: java, jdbc

**Background**

I am using and closing a lot of Prepared/Callable Statements and ResultSet, so I made a global static method to clean up in the finally section.

It is obvious those can't be null most of time, I just want to make sure adding for null check instead of closing right away.

So far there was no problem at all using this methods, but is this thread safe?
If not, do I need to use synchronized method instead of plain static method?

**Usage** Other Threaded Class

```
private PreparedStatement psUpdate = null;
try {....}
catch(Exception e) {...}
finally
{
    Utils.NullCheckClose(this.psUpdate, this.getProcName());
}
```

**Declaration** Utils Class

```
public static void NullCheckClose(PreparedStatement temp, String threadname)
{
    try
    {
        if(temp != null)
            temp.close();
    }
    catch(Exception msg)
    {
        Logger.erLog(msg, threadname);
    }
    finally
    {
        temp = null;
    }
}

public static void NullCheckClose(CallableStatement temp, String threadname)
{
    try
    {
        if(temp != null)
            temp.close();
    }
    catch(Exception msg)
    {
        Logger.erLog(msg, threadname);
    }
    finally
    {
        temp = null;
    }
}

public static void NullCheckClose(ResultSet temp, String threadname)
{
    try
    {
        if(temp != null)
            temp.close();
    }
    catch(Exception msg)
    {
        Logger.erLog(msg, threadname);
    }
    finally
    {
        temp = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no state you are just using method. 
Synchronization is needed when you are sharing state. Utils does not store parameter values and then operate on them it just operates on them so no need of synchronization.

Rather synchronization is needed for `this.psUpdate` since its a state of the object. You should try to remove it a  member variable

```
Utils.NullCheckClose(this.psUpdate, this.getProcName());,<---this.psUpdate try to remove its as a member variable.
```

It is better to initialize  `PreparedStatement` or `CallableStatement` as a local variable than member variable.

Comment: Yes, no statements are shared among threads. Statements are initialized as a local variable, however, it uses the public static method to null check close.

Comment: You can not define local variable as `private`. It is a member variable. Please check your source code.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused with that term. Yes, it's a member variable and not local variable within the method. If I only use the Utils.NullCheckClose on the destructor side, it would not need to be synchronised, is that right? I mean it's only used when it's closing the thread or the process.